# Google Dataprep is having issues with UI during lookup feature

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

From this week, am facing issue with using lookup feature in google dataprep.

Steps to reproduce

1. Create a dataprep flow.
2. Import a two datasets (source dataset ,lookup dataset)
3. Create and edit recipe
4. choose a column and do a lookup
5. The window will open a lookup UI

Issue:

The lookup UI will normally display list of datasets to lookup but from this week its not displaying any dataset.

[image: snapshot of the UI]

Comment: I'm seeing the same, and have flagged it with Google & Trifacta on twitter

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the issue.
The issue seems to happen with google chrome latest version(72).
If i use version 69 , then the issue is not seen.
While its still an issue to be reported to trifacta as they should ideally test it with latest google chrome, for now i have a work around.
Hence thought of sharing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a Chrome 72 defect ( Issue 927066: Flexbox rendering changed between chrome 71 and 72 ). Dataprep has pushed a workaround for this issue and you should no longer see the problem occurring
Make sure that you clear the cache to ensure no older plugins are loaded

Answer (score -1):

I followed the steps you mentioned and was able to see list of dataset. This issue requires more information such as your project-id to troubleshoot. I advice that you open a [private issue on Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491499&template=1161178).

Google Groups are reserved for general product discussion, StackOverflow for technical questions whereas Issue Tracker for product bugs and feature requests. To get a better support you should post to the relevant forum. Please read the [Community Support](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/community) article for better understanding.